# Autocomplete for magento in netbeans

Tags: magento-1.9

Any one know how to do autocomplete for magento code as like this

```
$products_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addFieldToFilter('price', '574');
```

After visited the R.S. suggested link, modified the code but still after second method chain i.e. exactly at `addAttributeToSelect` autocomplete not working.

```
    $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    /* @var $productModel Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
    $products_collection = $productModel->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('price', '574');
```

Comment: Take  a look at http://edmondscommerce.github.io/magento/netbeans-autocomplete-on-magento-objects-called-by-magegetmodel.html

Comment: @R.S Please see the updated code for that after second method chain i.e. exactly at the method call `addAttributeToSelect` its not auto-completing

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31447793/yii2-autocomplete-chain-of-methods-in-netbeans

Comment: @R.S that question is asked by me only so how this two related will you please explain it. please in this regard I need autocomplete for magento since their documentation didn't explain any thing about functionalities and how we remember hundreds of hundreds function in mind. Yii is good in that they clearly explained in their documentation with autocomplete for search box in their official site. At least if possible give me the official magento with autocomplete in search with description what that function did. Thanks pal for your support. Hopefully expecting positive reply from you.

Comment: According to last link I provided, this seem to be a bug within netbeans "I'v found that there is keyword "$this" for type definitions in phpDocumentor: http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/types.html. NetBeans uses keyword "this" instead. I suggest to add keyword "$this" as alias for "this"."

Comment: @R.S Will you please suggest any alternative open source IDE for magento development.